# How to declare a reference to a empty stack in OCaml?

Tags: reference, ocaml, imperative-programming

perhaps I am being stupid here, so the more general question I want to ask is that how to declare a reference to a empty value of certain type in OCaml. Usually I declare a reference to a custom defined empty value, for example if I have a type `type point = Point of (int * int)` I would declare a reference like this `let a = ref (Point (0,0))`. However this is not satisfying because I have to ''come up" with a empty value myself. Also, if you look at the reference ``Stack'' module in the standard library (http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Stack.html), there is no empty value in it. How do you deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, stack has an empty value, since `Stack.create ()` will create an empty stack. What concerning your general question, then usually `None` is used as an empty value. And of course this automatically lifts your value into option. But this is intentional, since if you're creating a value as an empty, and then you're going to update it though the reference there is no type guarantee, that you will ever update it.

Example

```
let p0 = ref None in
...
p0 := Some (Point (0,0));
...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want it, you can do this:

```
let sr = ref (Stack.create ())
let () = Stack.push 42 !sr
```

OCaml's value restriction doesn't prevent it, it will initially have type '_a Stack.t ref, until you push into it.

But you hardly need it, Stack is already mutable.

Comment: (If you want an immutable stack, you can just use a list.)